# router-outlet or routes is not working in angularjs7?

Tags: angular

I have just started to learn angularjs 7 and i am going through an issue with routes

I have added router-outlet tag in  **app.component.html**

```
   <app-nav>
       <section>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </section>
   </app-nav>
```

Added this in **app-routing.module.ts**

```
       const routes: Routes = [
          {
              path: '', component: HomeComponent
          },
          {
              path: 'about', component: AboutComponent
          },
          {
              path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent
          },
          ];
```

and I have used routerLink attribute in **nav.componenet.html**

```
  <header>
      <div class="container">
          <a routerLink="/" class="logo">{{appTitle}}</a>
      <nav>
       <ul>
            <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
      </div>
  </header>
```

when i click the Home or About or Contact links , it doesn't redirects (routes) to home component or about component or contact component . Please let me know if i have done something wrong here .

Comment: Did you append `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` in your AppModule.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to add a new component using router-outlet inside another component which is  . so when i separate router-outlet from  it worked fine . Please find the solution below which worked  .

```
   <app-nav></app-nav>
   <section>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide a full view on router file. You need to import your array of routes and specify RouterModule.
Here is a good example: https://angular.io/guide/router